# How to save this code into a variable?

Tags: php

Is there any way to save this block of code into a PHP variable ? The reason of doing this is because I want to send it through `mail()`

```
echo 'MONDAY<BR>';
query_posts('meta_key=Date1&meta_value=MONDAY');  
while (have_posts()):
    the_post(); 
    if (in_category( '11' )) {
        echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'HomeSlogan', true);
    } else {
        the_title();
    }
    echo'<br>';
endwhile;
```

This is what zneak suggests

```
<?php

ob_start();
echo 'MONDAY<br>';
query_posts('meta_key=Date1&meta_value=MONDAY');  
while (have_posts()):
    the_post(); 
    if (in_category( '11' )) {
        echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'HomeSlogan', true);
    } else {
        the_title();
    }
    echo'<br>';
endwhile;

$mail = ob_get_contents();
echo $mail;
ob_end_clean();

?>
```

Comment: I don't know if that's how you always format your code, but it's highly unreadable.

Comment: @JaredFarrish What is a tool to use for formatting ? I use notepad, so a formatting shall be made later.

Comment: I format by hand, even in code editors; I learned originally with Notepad and used it for years (now I use Dreamweaver, but only for code highlighting). Do not *format later*; formatting in C-style languages like PHP is **for** human readability and helps you and others read and comprehend your code in a more consistent manner.

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_style#Code_appearance for more information.

Comment: Notepad is not an acceptable editor for any programming that exceeds more than about 5 lines.

Comment: @ThiefMaster - Notepad is a *great* way to learn the hard way how you *should* format your code. `;)` There are no crutches to lean on except how you've formatted it, especially in code longer than five lines.

Comment: You need to end output buffering before you attempt to write anything to the browser, because otherwise, well, it gets buffered. `ob_end_clean` disables output buffering and discards the contents of the buffer. Put your `echo` statement after the function call and it'll work.

Comment: @Jared: You need at least syntax highlighting unless you want to waste time finding quote-related typos... I'm not a friend of editors doing much more indentation besides keeping the current tab level so you don't have to type them everytime (which is probably the reason, notepad-using developers use shitty indentation)

Comment: @ThiefMaster - This is quite off-topic to the question. Sure, I understand what you're saying, but I disagree that Notepad is evil. I've seen horrible formatting come out of code editors as well. It's all a matter of whose pushing the keys. Wax on/wax off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use string concatenation and avoid `echo` altogether, or use output buffering. Output buffering saves your script's output into a buffer instead of sending it to the browser, so it's easier to use if you have functions that print text and that you can't really control.

```
// concatenation
$mail = 'MONDAY<br>';
$mail .= 'more text';
$mail .= 'yet more text';

// output buffering
ob_start();
echo 'MONDAY<br>';
echo 'more text';
echo 'yet more text';

$mail = ob_get_contents();
ob_end_clean();
```

For output buffering, you might want to read about [ob_start](http://php.net/ob-start), [ob_get_contents](http://php.net/ob-get-contents) and [ob_end_clean](http://php.net/ob-end-clean).

Comment: @Giorkouros - Put the `while` loop between `ob_start()` and `ob_get_contents()`.

Comment: @Giorkouros - You need to understand what's going on with output buffering; I suggest reading the [PHP manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php). But essentially, I believe your error is in putting the `echo` within the buffer, not after `ob_end_clean()`.